# SQL Server encrypting data

Tags: sql, sql-server, encryption

I have been asked to produce a system that is the middle point in a bunch of systems that handles payments to a small group or people. For it I will be required to store the peoples bank details.

What is a good way of encrypting this data to be stored within the database and then decrypt the data when required to pass onto the next system?

For this project I need to use Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: When I reread it I did think it was a bit harsh to SQL Server. I mentioned it to inform people that I can not freely change to another database implementation.

Comment: I've changed the wording slightly so you don't offend anyone inadvertently. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using SQL Server 2008 the you can use the built in transparent data encryption [(TDE)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510663.aspx). Check out and see if it fits the bill.

Answer (score 1):

I encrypt the values at application level along with an encryption key, and then pass this encrypted value to SQL Server.

When decrypting I pass the encrypted values to the application, and decrypt before using them within the application.

I prefer this method as it keeps the encryption method seperate from SQL Server.

Otherwise, if a user was to hack into your SQL Server, including your encrypted values, and you were using a `T-SQL User Defined Function`, they would have the ability to decrypt the values, making the encryption worthless.

Comment: My 'application' will most likely be a SSIS package. Is there any pre built encrypt / decrypt functions?